# Connect to remote file system from CF Java Application?

Tags: java, sftp, remote-desktop, sap-cloud-foundry

I have software installed in a remote system, I need to go to the `C:\Input` directory to that system from a java application deployed in SAP Cloud Foundry. While doing it from a main method from local system and connected to the destination system's network I'm able to connect but while deploying it in cloud not able to connect.

Answer (score 2):

SAP Cloud Foundry, of course, by default has no way to access any file on your computer or any other remote system. What you need to do is:

Make the files accessible to cloud foundry by either

- Provide a (on-premises) services to access to file e.g.

  - REST
  - SFTP
  - ...

  and access it then from cloud foundry -- you might need to configure your cloud connector if you do not want to have your services accessible via internet. SMB/SAMBA is a little bit tricky -- you'd have to use a java library to access those files.
- Upload/Replicate your files to a place which is accessible by CF, e.g. SAP CF Object Store.